# Hyperledger Fabric CouchDB index: "no matching index found"

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I have created an index alongside my chaincode in the `META-INF\statedb\couchdb\indexes` directory. The json for the index looks the following:

```
{
    "index": {
        "fields": ["id", "docType", "type"]
    },
    "ddoc" : "indexTestDoc",
    "name" : "indexTest",
    "type" : "json"
}
```

I can confirm that the index is being correctly created and updated in the process by looking at the logs:

```
 Created CouchDB index [indexTest] in state database [integrity-channel_approvalcc] using design document [_design/indexTestDoc]\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2019-08-15T10:48:01.42015813Z"}
```

The problem is that queries do not use the index, despite of me specifying the `use_index` attribute in the query string:

```
"{\"selector\":{\"docType\":\"foo\", \"type\":\"bar\"}, \"use_index\":[\"_design/indexTestDoc\", \"indexTest\"]}"
```

Is it a problem that I have `id` as an additional field in my index?

Comment: so the JSON is `{"selector":{"docType":"foo", "type":"bar"}, "use_index":"indexTestDoc"}` - use backslashes etc as you require

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index is on `["id","docType","type"]`, but you're not querying on `id`, so it can't use that index.

Either drop `id` from your index (recommended, because there's rarely, if ever, any reason to explicitly index `id`):

```
{
    "index": {
        "fields": ["id", "docType", "type"]
    },
    "ddoc" : "indexTestDoc",
    "name" : "indexTest",
    "type" : "json"
}
```

Or add it to your query:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "docType": "foo",
    "type": "bar",
    "id": "baz"
  },
  "use_index": [
    "_design/indexTestDoc",
    "indexTest"
  ]
}
```

If you really need an index on all three fields, but only want to query on two, make sure the two you query on are first.  I.e. put `id` last:

```
{
    "index": {
        "fields": ["docType", "type", "id"]
    },
    "ddoc" : "indexTestDoc",
    "name" : "indexTest",
    "type" : "json"
}
```

As mentioned above, there's rarely, if ever, any reason to create a manual index on `id`, anyway, since that's already unique, and has a built-in index already.  I can't think of any use-case where you'd ever want to create an index on id, so just remove that from your index. But the other solutions are still applicable for other indexes.